# Entity Framework: How to specify the name of Foreign Key column on a self-referencing Parent-Child relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, self-reference

I am trying to specify a column name to map a "Foreign Key" to using the Fluent API.  I am connecting to an instance of SQL Express.  I have searched Stack Overflow and Google, but many of the different configuration examples gave me the same result.

## Product Class

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product ParentProduct { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> ChildProducts { get; set; }
}
```

## Product Map to Entity Framework

```
public class ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductMap() {
        HasKey(p => p.ProductId);

        Property(p => p.Name)
            .IsRequired();

        // Self referencing foreign key association 
        Property(c => c.ParentId)
            .IsOptional();

    HasMany(c => c.ChildProducts)
        .WithOptional(c => c.ParentProduct)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
    }
}
```

## The Issue

The result when I run the program and EF creates the db is that the `ParentID` column comes out `NULL` and it creates a column that's called `ParentProduct_ProductId`. This column  contains the correct values for the ParentId.

I'm new to using the Fluent API with EF, so I'm chalking this one up to inexperience.  How do I get the auto-generated column to fill the `ParentId` column instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
public class ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductMap() {
        HasKey(p => p.ProductId);

        Property(p => p.Name)
            .IsRequired();

        // Self referencing foreign key association 
        Property(c => c.ParentId)
            .IsOptional();

        HasOptional(x => x.Parent)
            .WithMany(x => x.ChildProducts)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Damian.  Thanks for the response!  I used `HasOptional(x => x.ParentProduct)` but I think that was what you meant.  It's still giving me the same issue.  It creates the `ParentProduct_ProductId` column instead of using the ParentId column, and the ParentId is still NULL.  Is there other configuration I should try?  I noticed a lot of examples use the `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method, but I thought that was the same configuration that I was using by creating a mapping class.  Should this be done in this method instead?

Comment: I figured it out, but I can't post the answer yet.  It was related to the `OnModelCreating` method.  I did not register the mappings!